# add text-box on click of link

Tags: jquery

I need to add a text-box (within a container) on click of link.
Text-box will have value equal to 'href' of a link

My jQuery code is like:

```
 jQuery("a.link").click(function(event){
    jQuery('#link-container-text').text('<input type="text" onclick="this.select();" value="' + this.href + '" />');
  });
```

But instead of showing the text-box, it's showing me HTML code.

I need text-box, not HTML code.

**EDITED**

On click of another link, How can I remove just-added input from #link-container-text.

Comment: M , .text is for value , refer api here http://api.jquery.com/text/

Comment: you can use .html like what I suggested in my answer. It will remove the entire contents (innerHTML) of the element and replace it with whatever you specified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use .append or .html()

```
jQuery('#link-container-text').append('<input type="text" onclick="this.select();" value="(\'' + this.href + '\')" />');
```

.text is for value

removal of the added element

```
$("#link-container-text").find("input").remove();
```

Comment: Thanks, and how can I remove just-added input from #link-container-text

Answer (score 1):

Replace .text with [.html](http://api.jquery.com/html/). Note that this will replace the entire html of that element

```
 jQuery("a.link").click(function(event){
    jQuery('#link-container-text').html('<input type="text" onclick="this.select();" value="(\'' + this.href + '\')" />');
  });
```